# UWP Iot-Core Project in Visual Studio 2015 thinks it is WinRT and requires sealed classes and blocks generic collections etc

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I have an Windows 10 IoT-Core (latest) headed project which deploys and runs fine. I convert it to a headless (task) project and all of the sudden Visual Studio 2015 won't let me compile public classes. It says: Exporting unsealed types is unsupported. Please make WinRT type sealed.

Worse, it also does not let me use certain collection types, such as Dictionary, anymore: "Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary....' is not a valid WinRT type."

I have searched in vain for the setting -- and how to turn it off! Where can I kill this so I can compile again? My project is UWP, not WinRT.

Comment: UWP is just another name for WinRT version 1.4.  These are entirely normal restrictions, although it is certainly unclear to me what a "headless task project" might be.  You'll have to follow the guidance provided by the error messages.  Expose a dictionary as IReadOnlyDictionary to stay compatible with IMapView.

Comment: Thanks! Got it. That is the answer as far as I am concerned. I didn't know it was a synonym. Headless is the Windows 10 IoT-core fancy name for a background (no GUI infrastructure load) project. And it is simply run as a task on the IoT-core ARM platform.

Comment: Just want to add for completeness that this restriction only applies to exported (public) classes.